Integer arithmetic on Impala
I noticed that on Apache Impala (version 3.4.0), 32767 + 0 returns an integer, whereas 32768 + 0 returns a bigint. I'm curious to know if this is expected (i.e. not a bug in my version of Impala), and if so, what is the reason?
I was expecting 32768 + 0 to return an integer (not a bigint). Of course 32767 is the maximum value of a 16-bit signed integer, but if I execute select 32768 it still returns an integer (not a bigint). So it seems the addition operator is playing a role in the promotion to bigint.
UPDATE: I think I figured it out. Per the documentation,

When Impala encounters a numeric literal, it considers the type to be the "smallest" that can accurately represent the value. The type is promoted to larger or more accurate types if necessary, based on subsequent parts of an expression.

For integers, what this means is:
tinyint  + tinyint = smallint
smallint + tinyint = int
int      + tinyint = bigint

so it really does promote aggressively, I guess out of an abundance of caution.
So now I am wondering, if I have an int and a tinyint for which I already know their sum can be represented as an int, what is the recommended way to avoid the promotion to bigint? Just bite the bullet and use cast?
